# How can I specify in my package.json to only download one file or folder from a repo, rather than the whole thing?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a collection of small reusable scripts, stored as separate files in a single repo.

Is there a way I can use one of the scripts in a different project, without forcing it download the whole project?

`npm install https://github.com/skeddles/test/blob/master/test2/index.js`

> npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
>
> npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: https://github.com/skeddles/test/blob/master/test2/index.js.
>
> npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sisters of
> Satan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-29T19_08_48_510Z-debug.log

Comment: So essentially you want to add a single file to `dependencies` in package.json

Comment: @Bonfire yes, exactly

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work, so go ahead and manually add the link as a dependency. `"name" : "https://github.com/user/project/file.js"` If that doesn't work out, could you post the error?

Comment: @Bonfire when i try to install it is says "npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON | npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json". 

If I try to link to the folder that it's in, it just installs the base module.

If I try to add a package.json to the same folder as the file and npm i the package.json, it says: "npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format | npm ERR! code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE | npm ERR! TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format"

Comment: I'm curious if there is an answer to this, but my hunch is that this isn't possible (at least currently); `npm` is set up to handle entire packages, and is not exactly geared to picking and choosing which files from a package you need. I would go so far as to say that, generally speaking, a single package that you'd install from `npm` would include files that are all inter-dependent on one another; if they stand alone, they would be their own packages themselves.

Comment: @esqew yeah these could be single packages, but I was hoping to avoid adding tons of repos to my github, and they could be a bit more organized if they were in one repo, plus i could have examples combining them